# Clean up old internet accounts

Tags: mac, settings, library

Over the years I've tried lots of different hosting services in my Mac, so I've got mail, contacts, calendars, etc. from Gmail, outlook.com, and a couple different smaller ones.

I deleted them from Internet Accounts and now only have iCloud in there, but the old stuff still lives on disk. Is there any way to clean that out, aside from just finding the old ones and manually deleting them?

Specifically, I'm backing up my data once in awhile by just zipping up the contents of the mail, bookmarks, calendar, contacts, notes, etc. folders in the library, but I'm getting a bunch of old junk in the backups that's eating up a lot of space.

Comment: To clarify, you go to your library and compress the contents of your email database on a .zip file?

Comment: @jaime .tgz - but yes, I looked up the location of the various places where notes, email, bookmarks, contacts, calendar, reminders are stored, and I’m just grabbing each of those directories, which mostly contain sqlite files and some stuff I don’t know what they are - which includes data from all the old accounts too. Not super usable, but kind of an emergency backup in case I completely lose my account and computer.

Comment: In my experience it takes some time for Mail to clean up its databases, specially if dealing with big email accounts (15GB or more), but eventually everything goes. I'd have to look for the location of the other content you mention but my guess is what's taking up space is mail.